# Why iTunes Connect reject my app?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I got the following error message from iTunes Connect.

Performance - 2.3.10

We noticed that your app or its metadata includes irrelevant third-party platform information.

Specifically, your app icon still contains imagery of an Android device.

Referencing third-party platforms in your app or its metadata is not permitted on the App Store unless there is specific interactive functionality.

We've attached screenshot(s) for your reference.

Next Steps

Please remove all instances of this information from your app and its metadata, including the app description, What's New info, previews, and screenshots.

Since your iTunes Connect status is Rejected, a new binary will be required. Make the desired metadata changes when you upload the new binary.

NOTE: Please be sure to make any metadata changes to all app localizations by selecting each specific localization and making appropriate changes.

But I didn't modify anything since previous version.
So, I have no idea what is wrong of my app. I can't believe icons have problems. 
Please let me know how can I fix the problem?

Comment: can you add the icons and the screenshots for your app. I think your app icon has some resemblance like a android device etc.

Comment: From the error message it seems clear: "Your app icon still contains imagery of an Android device." and they've sent you a screenshot as a reference. Can you add it to the question?

Comment: Same issue. How did u solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple keeps improving review rules, so its not necessary that if review passed last time it should also pass this time.

It seems there are 2 problems.

1)Problem with app icon

2)Reference to third party library.

Comment: I asked to apple and he said my app have a problem of icons. I will design icons again. Thank you.